# How to make default layout in cakephp3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Actually I work on **cakephp3** project.

I want to change the style of the website and put an existing template.
I found a tutorial on how to do that, but I think it was for **cakephp2**, because I didn't find any file called `Dafault.ctp` in **View** folder.

And I tried to put the html code of my template in the `home.ctp`, but I saw the top-bar navigation which contains Documentation API ...
So where is the Default Layout in **cakephp3**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cakephp3 Layouts are in `src/Template/Layout/`. your view file always use `default.ctp` file, but you can use other layouts.

```
// From a controller
public function admin_view()
{
    // Set the layout.
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('admin');

    // Before 3.1
    $this->layout = 'admin';
}
// From a view file
$this->layout = 'loggedin';
```

a better definition in cakephp3 doc [here.](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#layouts)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I solved my problem..

I found the `Default.ctp`
He is in `Template->Layout->Default.ctp`

contrary to cakephp2 `View->Layouts-Default.ctp`